# Watin and Fluent automation - reference to current browser

Tags: automated-tests, watin, functional-testing, fluentautomation

I am using Fluent Automation in my project to create more human-readable tests. Info available here http://fluent.stirno.com/ and on GitHub: https://github.com/stirno/FluentAutomation

I need to be able to perform some things that are not implemented with fluent automation and would like to be able to get a hold of the browser or WatiN element. I am actually trying to run a LINQ query such as this:

```
var indicators = from i in this.CurrentBrowser.Links
where i.Url.Contains("LeadsMine.aspx?flag")
select i;
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just a reference for anyone that may find this later. We had a discussion about how to deal with this as part of a [Fluent Automation GitHub Issue](https://github.com/stirno/FluentAutomation/issues/61), with a couple different solutions.

Ideally any user interaction would be dealt with using the actual `I.Click("#button")` type actions, but in a fringe case like this where you have something like plugin/flash/java/you-name-it based UI elements, you either need to:

1. Add an extension method to support this, as lstanczyk did, or
2. Do something like a click event on an invisible or off-screen element, with an onclick that fires a JavaScript API to work with the plugin.

lstanczyk's own solution was adding an extension method:

```
public static void RunScript(this FluentAutomation.Interfaces.INativeActionSyntaxProvider I, string scriptCode)
{
    FluentAutomation.Element bodyTag = I.Find("body").Invoke() as FluentAutomation.Element;
    bodyTag.AutomationElement.DomContainer.RunScript(scriptCode);
}
```

And then invoking it with `I.RunScript(script);` where `script` is JavaScript in a string.